# I get two error messages when trying to insert a data to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I get these two error messages,

> 'ExecuteReader' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1.MySqlCommand'

> Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()' {This error occurs in (query, conn) field}

Little explanation about what I am trying to do

Here I am trying to make an application that will input data to separate databases (Men, Women and Kids) using If pub = "" (pub is mentioned in another) Then according to ComboBox1 the table may get differ. According to the table the values need to be inserted.

This is the code I am using

```
 Dim T As String
    T = ComboBox1.Text

    If pub = "Women" Then
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=women_clothing"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "INSERT INTO [" + T + "] VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & Val(TextBox5.Text) & "," & Val(TextBox6.Text) & ");"
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
            reader = Command.ExecuteReader
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try

        loadtable()

    ElseIf pub = "Men" Then


    Else

    End If

    loadtable()
```

Thank You

Comment: It appears that you wrote the code before adding a reference to MySQL Connector, which in turn led VS to offer to create the MySqlCommand class for you, and you accepted it. Remove that automatically created class

Comment: I think that "Command.ExecuteReader" should be command.ExecuteReader... At least is what you defined in the previous line... command, not "Command".

Comment: @Martheen I will check it. Thank you. :D

Comment: @Gi1ber7 VB.NET is case insensitive

Comment: @Martheen It Worked. Thank you So much.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use ExecuteReader for executing a statement that inserts data. ExecuteReader is for SELECT queries. ExecuteNonQuery is for INSERTs

Your code should look like:

```
  Using conn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=women_clothing")

    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6)", conn)

      conn.Open()

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox2.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TextBox3.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TextBox4.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TextBox5.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", TextBox6.Text)

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
  End Using
```

I've also demonstrated how to use parameters; **always use parameters**. Your code as it stands is massively at risk of [SQL injection attack hacking](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vtech+hack+sql), and if that doesn't dissuade you enough to not write code in this way, bear in mind that your app will crash if anyone enters an apostrophe in one of your textboxes (which will then give the more astute tech whizzkids using it the idea that it's prone to injection hacking, then they will break into it) which looks bad to the end user (and makes them complain to your helpdesk/you).

It doesn't matter that "it's only a simple app for my grandma to index her vinyl collection" - this is about NOT learning a pattern of behavior that is plain risky, bordering on career-limiting if you want to take your coding skills into the software development world. As the VTech hack linked above shows, there are now 5 million images of children floating around out there whose parents never authorized their release, all because a few people didn't take proper precautions in doing their job. If any of my developers wrote an injection prone SQL, given the nature of one of the industries I work in, they'd just get fired.

Also, please get into the habit of renaming your textboxes after you add them to the form. It's incredibly difficult for anyone (yourself included, 6 months down the line) to have to constantly look up "hmm, what is the first name textbox? is it textbox2 or textbox3?" it takes about 2 seconds to type something new in the (Name) line of the property grid after you add the textbox to the form; `firstNameTextBox` is far better than `textBox2`

Answer (score 0):

With credit to @Caius, this is a variation using `ConnectionStringBuilder`, a `With` block, a composite `Using` block and string interpolation, just for illustration.

**NOTE** the use of `As` in lieu of `=` when declaring the connection and command; this is to formally set the types rather than rely on `Infer` to determine them.

```
Dim connStr As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {
    .Server = "localhost",
    .Database = "women_clothing",
    .UserID = "root",
    .Password = "1234"
}
' -> "server=localhost;database=women_clothing;user id=root;password=1234"

Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr.ConnectionString),
    cmd As New MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [{T}] VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6)", conn)
    conn.Open()
    With cmd
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", TextBox2.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TextBox3.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TextBox4.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TextBox5.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", TextBox6.Text)
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    conn.Close()
End Using
```